# Salesforce list of stable

Tags: apex

```
public class OCVResponseWrapper {
   
    public Boolean done;
    public String totalSize;
    public list<RecordWrapper> records;
    public string nextRecordsUrl;
   
    public class RecordWrapper {
        public attributesWrapper attributes;
        public String Id;
        public Cases Cases {get;set;}
       
        public RecordWrapper() {
            attributes = new attributesWrapper();            
        }
    }
   
    public class Cases {
        public Integer totalSize;
        public Boolean done;
        public list<CaseRecordWrapper> records;
    }
   
    public Class CaseRecordWrapper {
       
       
        public attributesWrapper attributes;
        public String Id {get;set;}
        public String CaseNumber {get;set;}
        public String CreatedById {get;set;}
        public CreatedBy CreatedBy {get;set;}
        public String OwnerId {get;set;}
        public Owner Owner {get;set;}
           public String ContactId {get;set;}
           public Contact Contact {get;set;}
        public String Origin {get;set;}
        public String Status {get;set;}
        public String Reason {get;set;}
        public String GC_Secondary_Reason_Descr{get;set;} //CustomFieldValue
        //public string Secondary_Reason{get;set;}
        public String CreatedDate {get;set;}
        public String ClosedDate {get;set;}
        public String LastModifiedDate {get;set;}
        public String Description {get;set;}
        public String Subject {get;set;}
           public String RecordTypeId {get;set;}
           public RecordType RecordType {get;set;}
       
    }
   
    public class CreatedBy {
        public attributesWrapper attributes;
        public String Name;
    }
   
    public class Owner {
        public attributesWrapper attributes;
        public String Name;
    }
       
    public class attributesWrapper {
        public string type;
        public string url;
       
    }

}
```

Here I want to define `GC_Secondary_Reason_Descr__c` custom field in the wrapper class. How can I define a custom field? It could not take --c

Comment: Simply put, you can't have the `__c` in your wrapper class. Apex forbids that from being used in an identifier (i.e. the name of a variable, property, method, or class). You'll need to make do with the field name without that (or, honestly, just use the `Case` object instead of creating a wrapper for it).

Comment: OCVResponseWrapper QRRW = (OCVResponseWrapper)Json.deserialize(response, OCVResponseWrapper.class);

i want to deserialize in the above code... i get "GC_Secondary_Reason_Descr__c"  as null in the above deserialize line.... due to query name and wrapper defined name are mis-match.. how can i resolve this

Comment: pls solve my problem..its emergency

Comment: can u provide any solution for this?

Comment: Post the JSON you are trying to deserialize and we can tell you whether it is possible

Comment: @fred As an educated guess, I'm guessing the results from `/services/data/vXX.X/query`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write a wrapper, and in fact, are creating a lot of unnecessary work for yourself. Just use sObject instead:

```
public class QueryResultWrapper {
  public string nextRecordsUrl;
  public Integer totalSize;
  public Boolean done;
  public List<sObject> records;
}
```

This simple class will handle any record-based SOQL query response. If you want to make it handle just cases, use Case instead:

```
public class CaseQueryResultWrapper {
  public string nextRecordsUrl;
  public Integer totalSize;
  public Boolean done;
  public List<Case> records;
}
```

Comment: i have some doubts in pagination logic for next and previous methods()